# How to move the first element of each line to the end of that line in text files?

Tags: java, text-files

I have a text file trying to move the first element of the line to the end of line in Java

```
4, 2,-2,2,0,2,-2,-2,2,2,-2
5,-2,-2,0,0,0,-2,-2,-2,0,-2
6, 2,-2,2,0,2,-2,-2,2,2,-2
5,-2,-2,0,0,0,-2,-2,-2,0,-2
7, 2,-2,2,0,2,-2,-2,2,2,-2
5,-2,-2,0,0,0,-2,-2,-2,0,-2
```

I need to move the first number to the end of the line. For example:

```
2,-2,2,0,2,-2,-2,2,2,-2,4
-2,-2,0,0,0,-2,-2,-2,0,-2,5
2,-2,2,0,2,-2,-2,2,2,-2,6
-2,-2,0,0,0,-2,-2,-2,0,-2,5
2,-2,2,0,2,-2,-2,2,2,-2,7
-2,-2,0,0,0,-2,-2,-2,0,-2,5
```

Any help please

Comment: Have you written any code yet which can read and/or write from/to a text file in Java?

Comment: Well, read the file, move the first number and write the resulting line back to a new file. What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working script:

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("input.txt"));
     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.replaceAll("([^,]+),(.*)", "$2,$1\r\n");
        bw.write(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}
```

The "secret sauce" in this otherwise boilerplate code is the following regex string replacement:

```
line = line.replaceAll("([^,]+),(.*)", "$2,$1\r\n");
```

This matches and captures the very first term in one capture group, along with everything which follows the first comma in a second capture group.  Then it replaces with `$2,$1` to effectively move the first CSV term to the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks @tim . it does not work, the values in the first lines still in the same position

Comment: So you are saying that the `output.txt` file is completely identical to `input.txt`?  Or something else?

Comment: not identical , after running the code all the lines in the  input file are written in one line in the output file!!! and the values in the beginning of each line still in the same positions

Comment: I didn't get a chance to completely test my answer, sorry.